# Is there a performance hit with a maxElementsInMemory too big in ehcache config

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

Just wanted to know if there was a performance impact to setting a maxElementsInMemory much higher than what is actually used? For example, a max of 10,000 and using only 100.

ehcache.xml

```
<defaultCache
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    timeToIdleSeconds="7200"
    timeToLiveSeconds="0"/>
```

Context: I am using ehcache with hibernate and I want all records of a table (all entities) to be cached. From one customer to another, the number of records in that table varies so it is hard to set a precise max.

Thanks!

Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is none. This is just a *max* value. If your cache only holds 100 items, you will pay the cost of a map holding 100 elements. The upper limit has nothing to do here.

You can safely use much higher limit (underneath it is a simple [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)) although it is hard to justify such a choice.

Comment: Right tks. But won't this max be used to set the initial capacity of the ConcurrentHashMap? This would have an impact, no?

Comment: @Marc: quickly searching the EhCache code base proves it does not use the max value to initialize the map. And even if it was - bigger `initialCapacity` won't harm performance, it will only use more memory (which will harm performance after all, but you get my point).